# SSL certificate in the load balancer

Tags: ssl, certificate, tomcat7, load-balancing, f5

I have an application running in Tomcat and doesn't use Apache. The certificate is offloaded in the load balancer. Http works fine but https does not.

Do I need to configure/update tomcat/conf/server.xml if my SSL certificate is offloaded in the F5 load balancer?

Comment: With SSL offloading you just need a [Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html) without `SSLEnabled` parameter (or SSLEnabled=false)

Comment: wget https://localhost:8009/ is getting an error. GnuTLS: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

Comment: <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000" secure="true" scheme="https" SSLEnabled="false" />    ---- This is my connector in server.xml

Comment: you should send your traffic to port 8080

Comment: I am new on configuring this one. What if my http is on port 8080 and https on port 8009.

Comment: If the HTTPS termination is offloaded to the F5 then you need to access the F5 and not localhost (i.e. tomcat) with https. On tomcat only plain HTTP  should be available.

Comment: Yes, even though I access https://example.com:8009/, the error "GnuTLS: An unexpected TLS packet was received / Unable to establish SSL connection" comes up. Is this something to do on how server.xml was setup?